# SQL Server query xml column

Tags: sql-server, xml

I need to pull values from an XML column.  The table contains 3 fields with one being an XML column like below:

TransID   int, 
Place    varchar(20), 
Custom    XML

The XML column is structured as following:

```css
<Fields>
  <Field>
    <Id>9346-00155D1C204E</Id>
    <TransactionCode>0710</TransactionCode>
    <Amount>5.0000</Amount>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Id>A6F0-BA07EF3A7D43</Id>
    <TransactionCode>0885</TransactionCode>
    <Amount>57.9000</Amount>
  </Field>
   <Field>
    <Id>9BDA-7858FD182Z3C</Id>
    <TransactionCode>0935</TransactionCode>
    <Amount>25.85000</Amount>
  </Field>
 </Fields>
```

I need to be able to query the xml column and return only the value for the `<Amount>` if there is a `<Transaction code>` = 0935.  Note: there are records where this transaction code isn’t present, but it won't exist in the same record twice.

This is probably simple, but I’m having a problem returning just the `<amount>` value where the `<transaction code>` = 0935.

Comment: 'XML column. The table contains 3 fields' I am really sorry but could not get ur question.Plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
DECLARE @transCode VARCHAR(10) = '0935'
SELECT field.value('Amount[1]', 'decimal(18,5)') as Amount
FROM yourTable t
     OUTER APPLY t.Custom.nodes('/Fields/Field[TransactionCode=sql:variable("@transCode)"]') as x(field)
```

Alternatively, you can put logic for filtering `Field` by `TransactionCode` in SQL `WHERE` clause instead of in XPath expression, like so :

```
DECLARE @transCode VARCHAR(10) = '0935'
SELECT field.value('Amount[1]', 'decimal(18,5)') as Amount
FROM yourTable t
     OUTER APPLY t.Custom.nodes('/Fields/Field') as x(field)
WHERE field.value('TransactionCode[1]', 'varchar(10)') = @transCode
```

**<kbd>[`SQL Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5b37/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `XPath` like this in your TSQL:

```
SELECT
  *,
  Custom.value('(/Fields/Field[@Name="Id"]/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM YourTable
WHERE Custom.value('(/Fields/Field[@Name="Id"]/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') = '0655'
```